# Append dictionary values from another dictionary with the same keys

Tags: python

I have the following two dictionaries:

```
flow = {(49, 53): [122.92], (105, 34): [40.26], (47, 92): [85.28], ...} --- len(flow) = 134

dist= {(101, 15): 688, (47, 92): 156, (13, 62): 208, ...} --- len(dist) = 172
```

All the keys of `flow` are contained in `dist` (`flow` keys are a subset of `dist` keys), and I basically want to append all the distances in `dist` to the values of `flow`, to get the following:

```
flow_dist = {(49, 53): [122.92, 151], (105, 34): [40.26, 203], (47, 92): [85.28, 156], ...}
```

What I have so far:

```
list = [flow, dist]
new_dict = {key: [elem.get(key) for elem in list] for key in set().union(*list)}
```

Output: `flow_dist = {(49, 53): [[122.92], 151], (105, 34): [[40.26], 203], (47, 92): [[85.28], 156], ...}`

The problem is the values are `[[value1], value2]` instead of `[value1, value2]`.

Can someone help? Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't call your list `list`.  `list` is a keyword in python (e.g `a = list(1, 2, 3)`)

Comment: Your flow values are lists. Either don't use lists for flow values, or add `[0]` after retrieving your first value in your new dictionary.

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo `list` is not exactly a keyword. It's a standard library function. Yeah, it's better not to name your variables `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flow_dist = flow.copy()
for x in flow:
    if x in dist:
        flow_dist[x].append(dist[x])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```py
{key: [value] + flow.get(key, []) for key, value in dist.items()}
```

Example:

```py
In [11]: dist
Out[11]: {(101, 15): 688, (47, 92): 156, (13, 62): 208}

In [12]: flow
Out[12]: {(49, 53): [122.92], (105, 34): [40.26], (47, 92): [85.28]}

In [13]: {key: [value] + flow.get(key, []) for key, value in dist.items()}
Out[13]: {(101, 15): [688], (47, 92): [156, 85.28], (13, 62): [208]}
```